# Vote up down total max

Tags: php, vote

Hey tried to search for similar but guess my english fail me lol, well here is what i need help with, im trying to make a vote system with up/down vote and wanna show it like this

5.3/10

but have no idea how to make total "5.3" not go over 100% = 10 here is my code so far

```
<?php 

$Vote_up = 804;
$Vote_down = 942;
$total = $Vote_up + $Vote_down;
$result = 100;

echo number_format($total/$result,1,",",".") . "/10"; 

?>
```

result is 17,5/10

ps. new to php so be easy on me ^^

Comment: how do you want to calculate this `5.3/10` ?  5.3 is nothing like the other numbers in your question...

Comment: It seems that your math is incorrect. Are you certain of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @msturdy; ye sorry notice that now, not good to do both post and change at same time lol, last one is correct 17.5..  @Tyymo ya got that feeling to lol yupp certain i am atleast wanna make total / 10 but kinda stuck how im gonna make 100% to 10 in decimals

Comment: think about how you will define the results... you need to decide on how you want to show this to the user!

Comment: i wanna show it as example 5/10 if 555 vote up and down (1110 total) and i want the /10 to be 100%, if im making any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am really bad at maths but i think this should be work

```
$Vote_up = 555;
$Vote_down = 555;
$total = $Vote_up + $Vote_down;

if( $total <= 0 ){
    $score = -11;
} else {
    $score = (($Vote_up / $total) + ($Vote_down / $total) * 10) * -1;
}
echo floor( $score + 11 ) . '/10';
```

if someone have a better solution, please i would like to know it - thanks!

Comment: realy nice exactly how i wanted it only problem is it show 6/10 if its 50/50 but atleast it dosnt go over 10 as i wanted :D